# Not a Long-Winded Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I'm not very serious when I am rolled.
>   If memory serves me, I spread uncontrolled.
>   If you see more of me, I'll be given more slack.
>   With her, I'm famously pink or black.
>
> I was expecting against 101 before.
>   On my own, I'm a greedy man wanting more.
>   When I stole from a bank, I thought God was all,
>   With nothing behind me, the children will call.

**What am I?**
**In your answer, please explain each line.**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you are a

> pant

I'm not very serious when I am rolled.

> flippant - to flip is to roll, and flippant is not serious.

If memory serves me, I spread uncontrolled.

> rampant - RAM is the memory.

If you see more of me, I'll be given more slack.

> Pants (plural) as long trousers or slacks.

With her, I'm famously pink or black.

> The movie character the pink panther, or an actual black panther

I was expecting against 101 before.

> anticipant - anti is against and CI is 101.

On my own, I'm a greedy man wanting more.

> pantalone -  one of the principal characters from commedia dell'arte,  with exceptional greed.

When I stole from a bank, I thought God was all,

> Pantheist - identifies the universe with God, and heist is the bank-job.

With nothing behind me, the children will call.

> Panto - or pantomime for a children's show.

Title: Not a Long-Winded Riddle

> A short breath is not long-winded.

Comment: Very nice! But note [rot13] gur cvax cnagure vf n qvnzbaq naq n pnegbba punenpgre, ohg bayl fbeg bs n zbivr punenpgre.

Comment: [rot13] oynpx cnagure vf nyfb n snzbhf zbivr.